# Alpine 3.18 with cURL 8.2.1 not respecting /etc/hosts on .localhost domain extensions

Tags: docker, curl, alpine-linux

Recently we have been updating our Docker images to the latest version of Alpine 3.18.

With this change we noticed that our application was not able to send HTTP requests using cURL to other containers that are running on the same host. This was made possible by using the `extra_hosts` flag in our Docker Compose file.

Whilst debugging we noticed that Alpine recently switched to cURL version 8, specifically 8.2.1. In this update it feels like it is ignoring the `/etc/hosts` file, which is where Docker writes the `extra_hosts` configuration.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    test:
        image: alpine:3.18
        extra_hosts:
            - example.localhost:host-gateway
```

Run container: `docker-compose run test sh`
Inside the container:

Installing cURL:

```
apk add curl
```

Installed version:

```
/ # curl --version
curl 8.2.1 (aarch64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/8.2.1 OpenSSL/3.1.2 zlib/1.2.13 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.4 nghttp2/1.55.1
Release-Date: 2023-07-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp ws wss
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Execute cURL:

```
/ # curl -v example.localhost
* processing: example.localhost
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Address not available
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to example.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
curl: (7) Failed to connect to example.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Which is odd since

```
/ # cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.65.254  example.localhost
172.20.0.3      76a7dfa28161
```

And

```
/ # ping example.localhost
PING example.localhost (192.168.65.254): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.65.254: seq=0 ttl=62 time=2.224 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.254: seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.731 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.65.254: seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.322 ms
^C
--- example.localhost ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.322/1.092/2.224 ms
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `.localhost` TLD should be restricted to a loopback as per [RFC2606](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606). Have you tested with another TLD? You could use `whatever.example.org`

Comment: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/9296 seems to backup your claim that it is a recent change indeed. So the usage of `.localhost` as your TLD seems to be the root cause of your issue.

Comment: Wow just tried it with a different domain extension, looks like you are right! I would have never figured this out. If you could add your answer as a solution I could mark it as solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top level domain (TLD) `.localhost` should be treated as `localhost`, as per [RFC 2606](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606)

> The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in
> host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the
> loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use
> would conflict with widely deployed code which assumes this use.

<sup>*Source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2606#section-2*</sup>

This is further documented in [RFC 6761](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6761)

> The domain "localhost." and any names falling within ".localhost."
> are special in the following ways:

> 3. Name resolution APIs and libraries SHOULD recognize localhost
>    names as special and SHOULD always return the IP loopback address
>    for address queries and negative responses for all other query
>    types.  Name resolution APIs SHOULD NOT send queries for
>    localhost names to their configured caching DNS server(s).

<sup>*Source: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6761#section-6.3*</sup>

Which seems to be the rational behind its implementation in cURL as per this pull request: https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/9296.

---

This can be tested with the *Dockerfile*:

```bash
FROM alpine:3.18

RUN apk add --no-cache curl

ENTRYPOINT [ "curl", "--verbose", "--silent", "--connect-timeout", "0.1" ]
```

Running it with a `.localhost` TLD:

```bash
$ docker run \
    --rm \
    --add-host example.localhost:93.184.216.34 \
    $(docker build --quiet .) \
    example.localhost

* processing: example.localhost
*   Trying [::1]:80...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Address not available
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to example.localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection
```

Running it with another TLD, for example `.example`:

```bash
$ docker run \
    --rm \
    --add-host example.example:93.184.216.34 \
    $(docker build --quiet .) \
    example.example

* processing: example.example
*   Trying 93.184.216.34:80...
* Connected to example.example (93.184.216.34) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.example
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
> 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>404 - Not Found</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
        </body>
</html>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Mon, 21 Aug 2023 15:26:57 GMT
< Server: ECS (dcb/7F3C)
< Content-Length: 345
< 
{ [345 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host example.example left intact
```